# Derivation of the equation of backpropagation algorithm

Tags: math, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, derivative

Can someone provide a derivation of the equation he gets on 1:15 using quotient rule https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVId8KMsdUU&index=18&list=LL2gry7n2BsijUeah-oFnPSg
Pretty simple question, but I get another equation, so I'm stuck.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Your question probably belongs on math.stackexchange.com though.